# SQL: атомарен ли блок запросов на чтение?

Tags: sql, безопасность

В MySQL есть возможность объявления пользовательских переменных. В некоторых других СУБД есть аналоги этому. Вопрос: если я сделаю два sql-запроса на чтение, то возможна ли между ними операция записи? Пример:

```
SELECT @min_price:=MIN(price),@max_price:=MAX(price) FROM shop;
SELECT * FROM shop WHERE price=@min_price OR price=@max_price;
```

Пример взят из https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-user-variables.html. В частности, меня интересует, могут ли из таблицы, например, удалить максимальное значение после первого, но до второго запроса, так что второй запрос вернет некорректный результат.

Comment: автоинкримент независимый, ему транзакции innodb и lock myisam  не почем... так что если вы про айди записи то он изменится по любому между чтениями в случаи инсерта

Comment: Даже один select не атомарен

Comment: @Sergey,  спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Внутри транзакции с уровнем изоляции `SERIALIZABLE` - нет, в остальных случаях - да. `REPEATABLE READ` здесь не спасет от т.н. *phantom read* - он не даст другим транзакциям обновить уже существующие записи, но не спасет от добавления новых.

Comment: Если не сложно, приведите пример или ссылку на информацию.

Comment: @MikhailIonkin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems) https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html
подробный пример скорее всего не получится из-за отсутствия свободного времени, возможно, кто-то еще отпишет

Comment: ссылка хорошая, и именно за нее ставлю защиту вопроса.

Comment: Что такое `защита вопроса`?

Comment: @vp_arth, имелось в виду принятие ответа, или принятие решения вопроса, -- по аналогии с "защитой диплома", когда отвечающий "защищает" свое решение проблемы.

Answer (score -1):

А что мешает написать такой запрос :

```
SELECT * FROM shop WHERE price=MIN(price) OR price=MAX(price);
```

Comment: В данном случае -- ничего. Но в более сложных примерах хотелось бы пользоваться объявлением переменных.  Это позволило бы сократить код  и сделать его, как мне кажется, более понятным.

Comment: если дав запроса не объявляются как начало транцакции, то между ними могут произойти изменения

Comment: Можно поподбробней? В частности, привести пример, когда два запроса не объявляются как начало транзакции, и противоположный пример: когда два запроса объявляются как начало транзакции.

Comment: Вы команды серверу отправляете вручную или из программного кода?

Comment: А это важно? На данный момент я учусь. Но допустим, что вручную.

Comment: Написать то ни что не мешает (кроме отсутствия клавиатуры), но вот выполнить его MySQL помешает ... нельзя использовать групповые функции в фразе `where`